# request module is causes express.js to set headers

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using node with express and request modules. I could call `res.json` before I started using request to fetch info from another server. However, as soon as I'm trying to use `res.json` in the callback function in request, I would get the error message that the header has already been sent.

One solution would be to set the format header explicitly as `'application/json'`, however I don't want to unwrap `res.json`. Are there any other solutions to this? Has this been caused by the fact that express believes no header has been set and so presumptuously sends one on its own?

Code sample:
`
router.get('/app/:action', function (req, res) {

```
    switch(req.params.action) {
        case "search_gifs":
            //res.json(["no problem"]);
            request(
                {/*some params*/},
                function (error, response, body) {
                    res.json(["error"]);return;
                }
            );
            break;//I didn't add break but nothing is happening in default, but I'll try again with break
    }
```

`

Comment: Could you provide some code please ?

Comment: Beware that res.json also ends the request. You cannot send response twice in a request func, so please post a snippet of your code so we can inspect it.

Comment: So it seems like after adding `break` the problem did get solved, so I assume the seemingly harmless codes I added in `default` did have something to do with the header (and have I had access to the complete error log, I should've been seeing the error message coming from lines after `default`, but sadly I don't/didn't have the complete access).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, you are getting error like this `header has already been sent.`

Let me explain you in simple way,

You must be written `res.json` from multiple places as per your condition.

You are getting this error because `res.json` is executing multiple times.

When it execute first time it will not give you error but second time it will give you error because response is already sent.

Your code has some loop hole. Debug it.

Let me try to explain you in details with example here.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//
//  To generate error
//
app.get('/generate_error', function(req, res) {

    //
    //  When check_error query param is true, It will throw you error else
    //  all good
    //
    if (req.query.check_error) {

        //
        //  check_error is true so let's send response first here.
        //
        res.send('Hello World!');

    }

    //
    //  If check_error is true then it will try to send response again for
    //  same request.
    //  If check_error is false then it will by send response first time
    //  here so no error
    //
    res.send('Hello World!');

});

//
//  Solution 1 for above case
//
app.get('/ignore_error_1', function(req, res) {

    if (req.query.check_error) {

        res.send('Hello World!');

    } else {

        res.send('Hello World!');

    }

});

//
//  Solution 2 but different with solution 1
//
app.get('/ignore_error_2', function(req, res) {

    if (req.query.check_error) {

        //
        //  When you don't have anything to execute after sending response
        //  then just add return here.
        //  In other case you have to manage your code as per your
        //  requirement if you have anything needs to be executed after
        //  sending response from multiple places.
        //  NOTE : Make sure you will not execute res.json multiple times
        //
        return res.send('Hello World!');

    }

    return res.send('Hello World!');

});

app.listen(3000, function() {

    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')

});
```

Just execute this three get urls

```
/generate_error?check_error=true
/ignore_error_1?check_error=true
/ignore_error_2?check_error=true
```

Comment: The problem does have to do with the header. It got solved after I added break before `default`, which is calling a function that in turn has been trying to reset the header. I think it's not only worth mentioning what you've mentioned in the answer (namely that `res.json` is a wrapper of header setting and sending), but it's also worth mentioning that `break` should always be added after a case ends, however harmless the code looks without.

Comment: @andrew Yeah I agree with you `break` must be added if you are sending response from each `switch` case. I just explained you in details. I noticed you already mentioned about `break` in question. Hope it make sense.